# IE Conditional Stylesheet

Tags: css, internet-explorer, stylesheet

So I am trying to set up a conditional stylesheet for IE. However, it simply doesn't work.

Here is my code in the header:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ieStyle.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

1. My syntax seems to be correct
2. I know that the path to my stylesheet is correct
3. There are no X-UA-Compatible meta tags interferring

So what could my problem be?

Comment: are you sure the name is correct (with the upper S) and you have *nix permissions to load the file?

Comment: Does it load normally if you exclude the conditional comments?

Comment: Yes, it loads normally when I exclude the conditional comments. I am testing on IE 9

Comment: Try putting IE9's Browser Mode (from F12 dev tools) into IE8 or 7 and see if it loads then?

Comment: I was wrong... I am in IE 10. I put the browser mode lower and it worked! Thanks! My next question however, how can I target IE 10?

Comment: @sloth See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't target IE10 with conditional comments. Support for those has been dropped in IE10, due to it being far more "standards compliant" than past IE versions (and therefore mostly eliminating the need to specifically target it).

The only way to target IE10 specifically would be via JavaScript by checking the [`navigator.userAgent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.navigator.userAgent) string for values specific to IE10. This, however, is greatly frowned upon (I'll leave it up to you to research why, Google will turn up tons of stuff on why you should **not** use `userAgent`). Rather than check for what browser is being used (or appears to be used, as you can spoof `userAgent`), you should check if a particular piece of functionality that you want actually exists, and if not fall back on something else. The way you check depends on the functionality in question.

So you should ask yourself: "Why do I need to target IE10?". It's likely you don't actually want or need to do so, or that you can refactor what you have such that you shouldn't need to target specific browsers.